# After adding dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1 " facing error to "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"

Tags: android, dependencies, google-play-services, android-appcompat

After adding dependency "**com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1** " it shows error to "**com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0**" 
It shows that all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification.

My dependencies are like below:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`
implementation `com.android.support:design:28.0.0`
implementation `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3`
//GMS Services for location
implementation `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1`
```

The error is:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:media-compact-26.1.0.
```

If I remove gms dependency then the error for appcompact library has disappears. Any solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Add these lines in your `gradle` as dependencies

```
def support_libraries = "28.0.0"

implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_libraries"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_libraries"
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:$support_libraries"
```

If this doesn't work, I'll suggest you an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered in here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571055/4409113

```
Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:media-compact-26.1.0.
```

Try to add:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

In your `Build.gradle` dependencies.

Comment: Run this command on the terminal: `./gradlew app:dependencies` and add the output to your question to check what causes the issue.